# Websockets and Redis pubsub

Tags: haskell

Does anybody know where I can find an example of using wai-websockets with Redis pub-sub to send real-time notifications to the clients?

I have read the hacakge documentation for [wai-websockets](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-websockets) and [hedis](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis), but I am still unclear how I can combine the two to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone comes wondering to this post, I recently implemented a basic [hedis](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis) and [websockets](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets) app. A simple implementation would be run a hedis subscriber in a thread and a websocket in another thread and communicate via TChan.

Some sample code

```
main = do
  chan <- atomically $ newTChan
  a <- forkIO (subscribeProc chan)
  b <- forkIO (webSock chan)
  -- wait for a and b

-- Hedis subscriber
subscribeProc :: TChan B.ByteString -> IO ()
subscribeProc chan = do
  conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo
  pubSubCtrl <- newPubSubController [("redis-channel", chanHandler chan)] []
  forever $
    pubSubForever conn pubSubCtrl onInitialComplete
    `catch` (\(e :: SomeException) -> do
                Prelude.putStrLn $ "Got error: " ++ show e
                threadDelay $ 60*1000)


chanHandler :: TChan B.ByteString -> B.ByteString -> IO ()
chanHandler chan msg =
  atomically $ writeTChan chan (msg)

onInitialComplete :: IO ()
onInitialComplete = putStrLn
  "Redis acknowledged that mychannel is now subscribed"


-- websocket
webSock :: TChan B.ByteString -> IO ()
webSock chan = do
  WS.runServer appHost appPort $ handleConnection chan

handleConnection :: TChan B.ByteString -> WS.PendingConnection -> IO ()
handleConnection chan pending = do
  connection <- WS.acceptRequest pending
  loop chan connection
  where
    loop chan connection = do
      msg <- atomically $ readTChan chan
      putStrLn $ "got data " ++ show msg
      WS.sendTextData connection msg
      loop chan connection
```